# Run TTS in NSArray sequentially

Tags: objective-c, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

I have NSArray with words in it.
I want to app reads that tts sequentially and print the text in UILabel what app speak.
but word on label is shown the last one.

I tried time pause, etc

```
for (Word * w in ttswords) {
    [self speechword:w];
}

-(void)speechword:(Word*)w{

    utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:[w.title stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"~" withString:@""]];
    utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-US"];
    [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];

    _lb_title.text = w.title;

}
```

I want to execute one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to highlight the vocalized word is using the `speechSynthesizer:willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString:utterance:` method of the `AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` protocol.

If you don't use this delegate method, you won't be able to reach your goal.

Take a look at [this complete and useful example](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#speech-synthesis) *(ObjC and Swift)* that displays each vocalized word in a bold font with the speech synthesis.